# Short story about a group of young humans raised in a sealed and sterile environment, who later become the first interstellar crew

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I am trying to find a story I read in an anthology, probably from the fifties or sixties.

I believe it was written in the first person, about a group of young humans called Lapins (for experimental animals) raised in a sterile environment from birth in a university. I think the term was gnotobiotic. The research was medically motivated, but the group is suffering slow attrition from suicide out of isolation and meaninglessness.

However, one of them proposes to have them train and become the first interstellar crew to make contact with a recently discovered non terrestrial but "human" civilization to avoid carrying contaminating germs from Earth. This restores their sense of purpose and saves them.

Comment: https://www.gutenberg.org/files/61316/61316-h/61316-h.htm has some matches, but isn't first-person and they're Axenites, not Lapins. Also, they're already invading the planet of "Kansas" at the start of the story.

Comment: I remember reading this as well, in the 1970s.  Seems to me the kids were immune deficient, what would later be called "bubble children".

Comment: @FuzzyBoots "The Chemically Pure Warriors" (which I've read) is nothing like the story described here except for the use of "gnotobiotic."

Comment: That's fair. :-D I am amused, though, that the same author wrote a similar story which is a much better match. Maybe he had a type.

Comment: If someone posts the correct answer, you can accept by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Must be [World in a Bottle](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/51824/51824-h/51824-h.htm) by ALLEN KIM LANG

[image]

> "Not fallout, bacteria," I explained. **"I'm one of the Lapins from
> Central University."**
>
> "That's nice," the policeman said. "And I'm one of the Bjornsons, from
> Indiana State Police Post 1-A. What were you trying to do just now,
> break Mach One on wheels? Or do you maybe come from one of these
> foreign planets that don't know the American rules of the road?"
>
> I breathed deep, trying to find myself some oxygen. "I was born right
> here in Indiana," I said. "The reason I'm wearing this suit and helmet
> is that **I'm bacteriologically sterile."**
>
> "So maybe you could adopt a kid," Officer Bjornson suggested.
>
> "Sterile like germ-free," I said. "**Gnotobiotic**. I grew up in the Big
> Tank at Central University."